# Typescript - Generics? Or something else?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, polymorphism

I have a problem which produces these errors on the console.

```
Type 'WebFieldB' does not satisfy the constraint 'WebFieldA & WebFieldB'.
```

There are 2 classes generated by server, which shouldn't be changed.

```
class WebFieldA {
  readonly Name: string;
  readonly IsUpdatable: boolean;
}

class WebFieldB {
  readonly Name: string;
}
```

And this is my code:

```
interface IFieldInfo {
    name: string;
    isUpdatable: boolean;
}

class SomeField<T extends  WebFieldA & WebFieldB> implements IFieldInfo {
    field: T;

    constructor(pField: T) {
        this.field = pField;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this.field.Name;
    };

    get isUpdatable(): boolean {
        return this.field.IsUpdatable || false;
    }
}

let field1: IFieldInfo = new SomeField<WebFieldA>({Name: 'fieldA', IsUpdatable: false});
let field2: IFieldInfo = new SomeField<WebFieldB>({Name: 'fieldB'}); **// Here for WebFieldB is error**
let myCollection: Array<IFieldInfo> = [field1, field2];
```

What do I expect?
I would like to have a collection of `IFieldInfo` built from objects of 2 types: `WebFieldA` and `WebFieldB` (WFB has no `isUpdatable` property!). Unfortunately i can modify only my code, not `WebFieldA` or `WebFieldB`.

And maybe another idea, to make this without generics? I don't know...

Answer (score 2):

As @recursive suggests, your input field is going to be a `WebFieldA` *or* a `WebFieldB`, not a `WebFieldA` *and* a `WebFieldB`.  That means you should use `WebFieldA | WebFieldB` instead of `WebFieldA & WebFieldB`.

The implementation of `isUpdatable` is then a problem because it assumes there is an `IsUpdatable` field on `this.field`.  You can solve this with an appropriate type guard.  Don't use `instanceof` as in @recursive's answer, unless you only plan to pass in actual instances of `WebFieldA` and `WebFieldB` as opposed to objects with the same properties.  I see that your example code is using plain objects, so you should not use `instanceof`.

One type guard I like to use is the following useful function (it should probably be in a library):

```
function hasKey<K extends string>(key: K, obj: any): obj is {[P in K]: any} {
  return key in obj;
}
```

This just makes sure that an object has a particular key.  Then you can implement `isUpdatable` without errors like this:

```
get isUpdatable(): boolean {
    return hasKey('IsUpdatable',this.field) ? this.field.IsUpdatable : false;
}
```

---

This is a bit much, though.  Let's sidestep the type guard issue.  Notice that structurally speaking, `WebFieldA | WebFieldB` is very similar to a single interface like

```
interface SomeWebField {
  readonly Name: string;
  readonly IsUpdatable?: boolean; // optional
}
```

and notice that you're not making use of generics at all.  You might as well just replace the generic with `SomeWebField`:

```
class SomeField implements IFieldInfo {
    field: SomeWebField;

    constructor(pField: SomeWebField) {
        this.field = pField;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this.field.Name;
    };

    get isUpdatable(): boolean {
        return this.field.IsUpdatable || false;
    }
}

let field1: IFieldInfo = new SomeField({Name: 'fieldA', IsUpdatable: false});
let field2: IFieldInfo = new SomeField({Name: 'fieldB'}); 
let myCollection: Array<IFieldInfo> = [field1, field2];
```

Assuming you don't have other hidden use cases you haven't mentioned, the above should meet your needs without generics.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Of course. That helps. I wanted to know if there is another way to do that. And it is so easy... I think that topic is exhausted. Thanks a lot everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this will accomplish your end goal, but you can get your code to compile if you change it like this.

```
class SomeField<T extends (WebFieldA | WebFieldB)> implements IFieldInfo {
    // ....
    get isUpdatable(): boolean {
        return this.field instanceof WebFieldA && this.field.IsUpdatable;
    }
}
```

I made a few changes.  First I used `|` instead of `&` to indicate that `T` only needs to extend one of the classes, and not both.  Then, I added a type guard to the `isUpdatable` property getter, to ensure the property is only read if `T` is a `WebFieldA` or a subclass thereof.

Comment: You should probably change the type guard to something that tests 'this.field.IsUpdatable' directly (structurally), since the example code is testing against objects that are not `instanceof` the `WebFieldA` or `WebFieldB` classes.

Comment: @str1ct, be careful, test against `(new SomeField<WebFieldA>({Name: 'fieldA', IsUpdatable: true})).isUpdatable` at runtime